# TinyMCE How to Add Design and HTML view

Tags: tinymce, tinymce-4

Looking to Show two buttons in the footer of TinyMCE editor (Design and HTML), where need to allow user to write HTML directly in HTML mode.

[image: Switch Design and HTML mode]

I have tried `code` plugin which pops up a Source window, where I write HTML but I see new `P` and `SPAN` tags are added and `TABLE` tags are getting removed when I switch back to Content window. I am using TinyMCE 4.2.8

Comment: If you have having issues with content getting modified can you setup a TinyMCE Fiddle that shows what is happening?  Without seeing the starting content and your full TinyMCE init nobody can say why things might be getting changed.

Comment: Added a fiddle (http://fiddle.tinymce.com/Syfaab/4), but the issue is pretty straight. In source code window I paste a HTML like `<a href="something"><div>link</div></a>` then tinymce remove the anchor tag considering it as an invalid HTML, but for my requirement I want to completely remove this auto correction.

Comment: Your Fiddle does not load any content so I will just address the snippet you mention above.  TinyMCE (by design) creates well formed, valid (X)HTML so you can't turn that feature off.  Placing a block element (div) inside an inline element is invalid HTML so the editor is trying to fix it.  If you change the DIV to a SPAN the editor should not modify that content.

Answer (score 0):

The code plugin should be working fine for your needs (except that it opens a new editor in a window). If certain tags are being removed by TinyMce (here: `table`) it may be that you remove them in your content filtering settings: https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-filtering/#valid_elements

Comment: Thanks, but I am setting `valid_elements: "*[*]"` still I get TABLE and TD tags are getting removed also, lot of para and span tags getting introduced. Which I dont want to see

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are running into with tags getting removed is that TinyMCE is designed to create valid, well-formed (X)HTML. If you attempt to create invalid HTML the cleanup/validation routine will always do its best to cleanup the content to make it valid.

For example, if you change

`<a href="#"><div>link</div></a>`

... to ...

`<a href="#"><span class="abc">link</span></a>`

TinyMCE will not modify the link.

There is no way to disable this validation.

Comment: Thanks Michael, it will become difficult for me to manually fix all this invalid HTML. In my view, the client will copy the HTML from a third-party content management tool. So I cant predict what HTML will be pasted into the Source Editor and fixing issues manually also not possible. Are you sure no way we can disable auto validation/formatting in TinyMCE?

Comment: I am positive there is no way to completely disable the HTML validation.